# Can hardware vendor stop 3rd parties from enabling users do what vendor does not purport for?

Tags: software, hardware

Hardware vendor A sells devices X to end users. A wants users to use X in a particular fashion, for which it provides all the means (e.g. A wants users to only run software that A approves, and so A provides an application repository; users are not normally able to install apps not from this repo).

Tech company B creates very cool software S that users (would) adore, but it can't be bothered dancing to A's tune (e.g. meet their requirements for inclusion of S in A's application repository).

So B devises some technical means to install S on X (despite A's technical attempts to prevent that) and markets S to users of X.

Does A have any legal avenue to stop B from doing that (apart from voiding warranty for X)? Any jurisdiction.

---

Though parallels with Apple/Epic may be sound, this question is not specifically about them and in fact is as abstract as the title. A valid specific example is [hacking tractors to install unofficial software](https://www.vice.com/amp/en_us/article/xykkkd/why-american-farmers-are-hacking-their-tractors-with-ukrainian-firmware).

Comment: You talk about Epic v Apple. That case is pending.

Comment: @Trish Nope. To the best of my knowledge, Epic does not instruct users to jailbreak iOS to install its app. In any event, the matter before the court is not about that. This question is hypothetical, although I do see parallels with Epic/Apple and can imagine Epic jailbreaking iOS.

Comment: Well, Epic v Apple is that they want to break down the repository enforcement of Apple - but no through jailbreaking. So far... similar but not quite it, yes. (bt: their case vs. Google tried to establish the same pattern but fails miserably in my opinion because google play is not the only shop for Android as the Appstore is)